# Costura.Fody doesn't want to embed anything in C#, I've already done everything as shown

Tags: c#, fody

I installed `costura.fody` successfully, set the `FodyWeavers.xml`, yet still it doesnt say embedding (dll) in the console. I've tried launching my app and indeed it didn't embed anything. My DLLs are added as references and I also even added them as existing items. Using C# Visual Studio 2019.

[image: Console Screenshot]

Comment: Can you share your configuration and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are your referenced assemblies [marked "Copy Local"](https://github.com/Fody/Costura#details), are are you [including them explicitly](https://github.com/Fody/Costura#includeassemblies)?